# Why is this Ajax not working with my php and not making an alert happen?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am very new in programming websites I created a website already but am now attempting to add in a database. I have that all set up but ajax isnt working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my javascript code :

```html
<script>
            
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var method = "Get";
            var url = "data.php";
            var asynch = true;
            
            ajax.open(method, url, asynch);
            ajax.send();
            //recive ajax
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                {
                    alert(this.responseText);
                }
                
            }
            /*
            function chbg(color, name) {
                document.getElementById(name).style.backgroundColor = color;
                document.getElementById(name + 'Chore').style.backgroundColor = color;
                document.getElementById(name+ 'Bathroom').style.backgroundColor = color;
            }

            function openForm() {
                document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
            }

            function closeForm() {
                document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
            }
            */
        </script>
```

Here's the php all I'm trying to do right now is get the 2 to connect.

```html
<?php

echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Comment: You probably just need to move your `send()` below the point where you add the readystatechange handler. Unless you need the more advanced features of XHR, you might find it easier to use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I have moved it below and using alerts have found out that the ready state is always at a 1 right before the if statement. I also moved it in a function to see if it was a problem with the webpage loading too fast, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you're exactly trying to do but your php file just `echo` something and he does not `return` something so your responseText property is empty.